# elseif condition not work in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
**elseif** condition not work in **PHP**......
```

any one can solve this problem......

1st condition is for file image.png and 
2nd is folder image.png n 
3rd condition is for if both not found.....will display else.....

```
if(file_exists(SS_ROOT.'/thumbs/'.$folder['fid'].'.png'))
{
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$ss->settings['url'].'/thumbs/'.$file['fid'].'.png" />'; //file image code
}
elseif(file_exists(SS_ROOT.'/thumbs/'.$folder['fid'].'.png'))
{
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$ss->settings['url'].'/thumbs/'.$folder['fid'].'.png" />'; //folder image code
}
else
{
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$ss->settings['url'].'/art.jpg" />'; //default code.....
}
```

Comment: what is this line echo '<img src="'.$`enter code here`ss->settings['url'].'/thumbs/'.$folder['fid'].'.png" />';

Comment: The condition in the if and the else if is the same.

Comment: Give space between elseif condition

Comment: so which condition use in elseif

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your if-condition and elseif-condition are identical, so in cases where the elseif condition would be true are getting caught by the if-block and skipping over the rest of the code provided.

If the two conditions are not meant to be the same, you'll need to change one. If they are, then both blocks should be merged together.

Comment: Looking closer, it appears that in your if-condition you're checking for the existence of 

SS_ROOT.'/thumbs/'.$folder['fid'].'.png'

but you're displaying

SS_ROOT.'/thumbs/'.$file['fid'].'.png'


I think you want to change the condition to use the $file array instead of $folder.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see in your code, you would want the else if to check if that file does NOT exist, then execute that code.

```
if(file_exists(SS_ROOT.'/thumbs/'.$folder['fid'].'.png'))
{
echo '<img src="'.$ss->settings['url'].'/thumbs/'.$file['fid'].'.png" />';
}
else if(!file_exists(SS_ROOT.'/thumbs/'.$folder['fid'].'.png'))
{
echo '<img src="'.$ss->settings['url'].'/thumbs/'.$folder['fid'].'.png" />';
}
else
{
echo '<img src="'.$ss->settings['url'].'/art.jpg" />';
}
```

note the ! in else if(!file_exists(SS_ROOT.'/thumbs/'.$folder['fid'].'.png'))
Depending on your application, you may want the ! in the if, not the else if, i dont know.

more code from you could be helpful.

Comment: I notice there are quite a few "" and '', maybe you have 1 set too many which can quite easily occur in a situation like this and is easily overlooked. Or maybe you dont have enough.
echo '<img src="'.$ss->settings['url'].'/thumbs/'.$file['fid'].'.png" />';
i would code it as
echo '<img src="$ss->settings['url'] . '/thumbs/' . $file['fid'] . '.png'" />';

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file_exists(SS_ROOT.'/thumbs/'.$file['fid'].'.png'))
{
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$ss->settings['url'].'/thumbs/'.$file['fid'].'.png" />'; //file image code
}
elseif(file_exists(SS_ROOT.'/thumbs/'.$folder['fid'].'.png'))
{
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$ss->settings['url'].'/thumbs/'.$folder['fid'].'.png" />'; //folder image code
}
else
{
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$ss->settings['url'].'/art.jpg" />'; //default code.....
}
```